# What does "Gdx" class do in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a game in android using libgdx.

`batch.draw(background, 0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());`

I was trying to show an image on the screen when I came across `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`

What does `Gdx` represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Gdx` class is just a convenience container for platform specific versions of the classes providing graphics, files, audio etc.

From the [source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.java) for `Gdx` you can see that it only holds a bunch of static fields that are all publicly available:

```
public class Gdx {
    public static Application app;
    public static Graphics graphics;
    public static Audio audio;
    public static Input input;
    public static Files files;
    public static Net net;

    public static GL20 gl;
    public static GL20 gl20;
    public static GL30 gl30;
}
```

What **libGDX** does is to provide (by setting the fields for you) implementations for each of these interfaces that are platform specific, so for example the `app` field will contain a `IOSApplication` on IOS and a `GwtApplication` on PC.

Answer (score 0):

It is a class holding static references to the platform dependant interface implementations. Best is you just look in the sources to understand.

Comment: I looked at [link](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.html#:~:text=Class%20Gdx&text=Environment%20class%20holding%20references%20to,is%20not%20the%20rendering%20thread.) but couldn't understand